# Optional authentication service

Tags: feathersjs, feathers-authentication

TL;DR The problem is how to get the the user information from a `jwt`

I'm trying to get the information of a `user` from the `jwt` if one is sent on the request but I don't want to close the endpoint to only logged in users.

I don't want to close the endpoint with the `authenticate` hook but I don't know how to get the `user` information without it.

I'm using a local strategy with `jwt`.

Comment: can you describe specific problem for that you need user informtion without logged in of user.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you don't use the authentication hook, the authentication information of the request (if any) will be available in [params.authentication](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/services.html#params). You can do whatever you want with it in your own hook:

```
module.exports = () => async context => {
  const { authentication } = context.params;
  // authentication will e.g. be { strategy: 'jwt', accessToken }

  // do whatever you like here including throwing errors
}
```

To get the user information *or* allow anonymous access see the [Anonymous Authentication cookbook recipe](https://docs.feathersjs.com/cookbook/authentication/anonymous.html).

Comment: this will include the token and the strategy, but not the decoded user etc. correct?  that would need to be manual?

Comment: Yes but the anonymous strategy would handle all of that.

Comment: They way I did it since I was making a second call on the backend was that I just checked on the `params.header` if the token was been sent.

```if (params.headers && params.headers.authorization)
  await this.app.service('reservation').create(dataReserv, params)
else
    await this.app.service('reservation').create(dataReserv)```

Answer (score 1):

The method with "try/catch" is good, but there is another way based on **hooks**.

1) Create custom hooks `isAuth.js`:

```
module.exports = (context) => {
  return !!(context.params.headers.authorization
    && context.params.headers.authorization !== 'null'
    && context.params.headers.authorization !== '');
};
```

2) Fix the service `hooks.js`(`app.service('/my-url').hooks(hooks)`) in which method authorization will be optional.
NOTE: if the user is not authorized, then in "params.user" object "user" will be absent.

```
const { iff } = require('feathers-hooks-common');
const { authenticate } = require('@feathersjs/authentication').hooks;
const isAuth = require('isAuth');

module.exports = {
  before: {
    find: [iff(isAuth, authenticate('jwt'))],
  },
  after: {}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do a `try`/`catch` around the authenticate hook to attempt to authenticate a route but not fail because of it e.g.

```
const tryAuth = async hook => {
  try {
    return await authenticate(hook); 
  } catch(err) {
    // do nothing?
    return hook;
  }
};
```

in which case, if there was a valid token, you'll have `params.user` and `authenticated = true` otherwise not.

Answer (score 0):

This is the only method it worked for me.

```js
const { iff } = require('feathers-hooks-common');
const { authenticate } = require('@feathersjs/authentication').hooks;

module.exports = {
    before: {
        all: [iff(
            (({ params: { headers: { authorization }}}) => authorization),
            authenticate('jwt')
        )],
        find: [],
        get: [],
        create: [],
        update: [],
        patch: [],
        remove: []
    },

    after: {
        all: [],
        find: [],
        get: [],
        create: [],
        update: [],
        patch: [],
        remove: []
    },

    error: {
        all: [],
        find: [],
        get: [],
        create: [],
        update: [],
        patch: [],
        remove: []
    }
};
```

I just verified that the authorization token was sent.